# Print long JPG onto multiple pages OSX

Tags: macos, printing

I have a really long jpg comp I want to print out and annotate. My print options are to scale or fit to page, but I want it to print it to multiple pages, the cutoff points aren't important. I want it to fit the width and whatever is cut off, print to the next page. Is there a setting in OSX print options for this?!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are settings for this sort of thing in Photoshop.

Otherwise, you might want to check into a tool that is meant to take images and make them span multiple pages, like [Rasterbator](http://arje.net/rasterbator).